# Remove "manage" banner from Bitnami Wordpress with AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have created a Wordpress website with Bitnami and Amazon Web Service EC2.

There is a small icon in the lower right corner saying "Manage". I am trying to remove this banner. I have found this guide https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/bninfo/. It says that I have to "Log in to into your server console using SSH", but I have no idea where to find this in the AWS administration module.

Comment: Can't you hide it with CSS?

Comment: Do you know the `username/password` for that machine? You must have specified it when you launched it.

Comment: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to connect to your server via SSH as described in the guide below:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-connect-to-the-server-through-ssh

Then you need to perform the steps described in the guide:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/bninfo/#how-to-remove-the-banner